# Connecting Nav Web Service in php

Tags: php, web-services, nav

I am trying to connect the Nav Web Services in Php (followed by this [Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/freddyk/archive/2010/01/19/connecting-to-nav-web-services-from-php.aspx)).

but it's returning an error:

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'http://NavIP.com:7047/DynamicsNAV/WS/SystemService' : Start tag
>   expected, '<' not found.

Could you tell me where I went wrong?

thanks in advance..

my code is:

//client.php

```
     <?php
require_once("NTLMStream.php");
require_once("NTLMSoapClient.php");
try
{
// we unregister the current HTTP wrapper 
stream_wrapper_unregister('http'); 
// we register the new HTTP wrapper 
stream_wrapper_register('http', 'NTLMStream') or die("Failed to register protocol");
// Initialize Soap Client 
$baseURL = 'http://NavIp.Com:7047/DynamicsNAVPMS/WS/';
$client = new NTLMSoapClient($baseURL.'SystemService'); 
// Find the first Company in the Companies 
$result = $client->Companies(); 
$companies = $result->return_value; 
echo "Companies:<br>"; 
if (is_array($companies)) { 
  foreach($companies as $company) { 
    echo "$company<br>"; 
  } 
  $cur = $companies[0]; 
} 
else { 
  echo "$companies<br>"; 
  $cur = $companies; 
} 

}
catch(Exception $ex)
{
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am dealing with the exact same problem, but have not found a solution because they all come back to this same script. Your problem is that you are getting no result back because of a 401 error code (could not authenticate), which is exactly I where I am stuck as well. The script ends up using CURL to connect, but somehow that fails.

Comment: Hi bernhard,I am given wrong domain name that's y it's not return the result now working fine. Actually I had Solved this on 30th evening, but Iam not updated the solution here. any way thanks for giving response.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$client = new NTLMSoapClient(null, $baseURL.'SystemService');
```

You are wrongly providing **baseURL** which is being taken as **WSDL location**. In your code, seems like you are trying to provide the service endpoint. Try that.

You could also use a packet sniffer like 'Wireshark' to see what response you are getting. The expected response is an xml, which seems like it is not returning. Maybe it is returning a 401 unauthorized? That's not an XML response, that also could be a cause.

Also, where is define('USERPWD','user:pass'); in your code? Didn't you use authentication? I have a strong feeling you just need to define it. Make sure you define the 'domain' part in the username field if you are using a domain. So, 'domain\user:pass'.

This post is good: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/freddyk/archive/2010/01/19/connecting-to-nav-web-services-from-php.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using NTLM, try using Basic Authentication which is quite straight forward and then use cURL. It is easy peasy. See code below for a simple implementation. You can use SOAP or ODATA

You should also use a Chrome extension known as [Wizdler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wizdler/oebpmncolmhiapingjaagmapififiakb)

See sample code below for a Basic implementation

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://navdynamicsip.com:port/WebService/WS/COMPANY NAME/Page/webservice",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<Envelope xmlns=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n<Body>\n<Read xmlns=\"urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/webservice\"></Read>\n</Body>\n</Envelope>",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8",
        "SoapAction: urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/webservice",
        "Authorization: Basic " .base64_encode('username:password')
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable NTLM authentication in Navision and then in curl call use CURLAUTH_NTLM instead of CURLAUTH_BASIC

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).